# How to move rows with dates in them to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula to search for names and move that row to another sheet:

```
With Intersect(Sheet.UsedRange, Sheet.Columns("D"))
    .AutoFilter 1, "=Name"
    With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("A:G"))
        .Copy Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

Is there a way to use this same formula to only transfer rows from one sheet to another with dates in said cell?

Comment: This is kind of a hack, but then again, the need is a bit out of box... If you have dates and text in the same column and the date fields, you can try `.AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=">1/1/1990"` where 1/1/1990 is an arbitrary date way before the first date in your data (so that you capture all your needed data). P.s. - There is no way to say "only give me rows with dates" in an autofilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see your entire code to answer this question for sure - and a screenshot of your spreadsheet. I recommend posting it.

In the meantime, I can take a reasonable guess with what you have here right now.

You need to adjust your range on your autofilter to whatever the column that contains your dates is. Right now it is checking column D for a criteria of "=Name". You might also have to adjust your criteria as well. to "=Date" --- "date" being whatever your date is in string/text format. Since dates in excel are often actually numbers you might have to use the actual number unless you convert your date column to string/text - which I would probably recommend. .offset(2) looks weird, you might have to adjust that as well. I would assume "A:G" is the range that contains your entire table.

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm

Try this:

```
With Intersect(Sheet.UsedRange, Sheet.Columns("G")) ' assuming column G contains your dates.    
.AutoFilter Field:=1, "=Date" ' put your date in number or text format here as the criteria
```

Good Luck.

EDIT: Try this:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*/*"
```

Comment: All I am asking for is the ##/##/## equivalent to look in VBA... I tried ##/##/## and it didn't work. I don't want to look for a specific date either, I want any date. Also, D is correct in the column I am looking for. The reason for the Name there, is because there are cells in D that show text, as well as dates. A screenshot really isn't required for this question I think though. I thought I was pretty clear in my needs...sorry, also, offset 2 is there for a reason. All I need is one simple thing, the ##/##/## equivilent for VBA... please let me have my script the way I have it now. thanks.

Comment: Now that I understand your question, I would agree a screenshot is not necessary. I didn't understand that you had names and dates in the same column.

Comment: So would you use whytheq's answer? or stick with your own original, because yours will only pick up a date, not all dates... correct?

Comment: I would actually consider doing something like what Scott Holtzman suggested. You see, the problem is that dates in excel are just data, they can be either numbers or text but using autofilter you can't just say "give me all dates". However, you could do something like what Scott suggested(he assumed they were #'s) and try to set the autofilter criteria so that it would in a "hack" fashion only pick up dates. But it depends on whether your dates are numbers or text. If they are text you could set the autofilter to pick up on cells that contain "/" characters. e.g. see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I completely didn't think about using the "/"... that will work, sometimes I think too advanced for my own good. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In a column next to the table use a formula like `=ISTEXT(D2)`
The use the new column to do your filtering based on whether it is True or False.
This assumes that there are *only either* names or dates in column D i.e if there's an integer then this approach won't work.

**EDIT**

You could code the above using `worksheetfunction`. Try the following...

```
Sub test()

With Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            MsgBox (Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(.Range("D2")))
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no other way? I'd like to keep it where the script does all the work, not add another formula...

Comment: `ISTEXT` is codeable - see edit; you'd need to build this into a loop